# How to normalize after Gram Schmidt process

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I'm a bit confused about how to normalize after the Gram Schmidt process from my textbook.

http://i33.photobucket.com/albums/d86/warnexus/length_zps0429d297.png

I understand that to calculate the length of a vector is 
1) raise each component of the vector by two
2) add them to get a sum
3) take the square root of the sum.

Is the textbook getting the length by the three basis(which I enclosed in a blue rectangle in the image) or the three K's(k1,k2,k3)?

It seems like they are getting it from the three K's. But I do not know how the textbook got square root of 6 as the length.

For square root 3, they raise the components(1,1,1) by two and add which is three. Took the square root of 3 that is the length. I understand that.

I do not understand how they got the second one: the square root of 6 as the length. The textbook raise each of these components (-2/3,4/3,-2/3) by two. add them together and square root but I calculated square root of 24/9...

I understand how the textbook got third and final length. Raise these components (-1,0,1) by two. Add them and square root it which is square root of 2.

Am I seeing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets the length by the three Ks, because you are trying to normalize each of the Ks... You are correct that the second one is the $\sqrt{\frac{24}{9}}$. Which is equal to $\frac{\sqrt{24}}{\sqrt{9}}$... Which is $\frac{\sqrt{24}}{3}$.... Remember that $\sqrt{(4)(6)} = \sqrt{4}\sqrt{6} = 2\sqrt{6}$.. Now try diving by the length and see what you get.

Comment: But that is still (2 * square root of six)/3 as the length of k2. The textbook has square root of six.

Comment: No it does not. Just because sqrt(6) is one the bottom doesn't mean it's the length. Try diving the second vector by its length, (2*sqrt(6))/3, and see if you get their normalized version.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean! Now I really get it now. -2/3/2sqrt(6)/3 = -2/3 * 3/2sqrt(6) = -6/6sqrt(6) = -1/sqrt(6)!

Comment: Yay! Happy trails. Good luck on finals.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{\frac {24}{9}} = \frac {2 \sqrt 6} 3$$